# "Boot has failed, sleeping forever." Suggest some solution for this

Tags: windows-vista, installation, fedora

I downloaded Fedora from [here](http://spins.fedoraproject.org/kde/). While trying to install it, I am getting this error:

```
No root device found. 
Boot has failed, sleeping forever.
```

I tried searching on it (found [codehead](http://search.code-head.com/F-new-install-no-root-device-found-2316945) and [fedoraforum](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=234025)) and came to know that it is a known bug, but couldn't find any solution to it.

---

**Do you know any solution to this?**

OR

**Do you know a distribution of Fedora that does not have these problems?**

[I am trying to install Fedora on my Windows Vista machine]

Comment: I assume this is x86 linux:
Where do you get up to in the install? (Is it still looking for your DVD, or have you installed to the hard-drive and rebooted and now its looking for root?)

Did you create a root partition while installing? (or select auto)

Of course it will sleep forever; if it can't boot, what else should it do?

Is your BIOS boot order pointing to the drive containing grub/lilo/mbr/active?

Can you boot using the DVD into "recovery mode" and rebuild grub/lilo?

Have you taken the DVD out after rebooting? (or restored BIOS order)

In other words, more information would help.

Comment: Report it in RedHat's bugtracker ASAP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use ext3 filesystem for making live usb.

mkfs.ext3 /dev/sdb1
liveusb-creator --reset-mbr

Usb starts well